# Clip raster by extent creating Band 1,2,3 from Band 1 (Palette)

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

When I use the QGIS tool "Clip raster by extent," GDAL converts my single band raster into a 3-band raster.

Since the tool is derived from the translate utility, I tried to find an answer here: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html and suspect that it has to do with the additional options in -b or -mask.

**How do I make sure that the entire output value is stored in only one band?**

Here is the GDAL command:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 520636.49722751346 4475761.856155057 521442.7377043423 4474951.834824213 
-of GPKG "C:/--/16T.tif" C:/--/AppData/Local/Temp/
processing_iuNbsb/77823c08f31e4176aa435045a4164c53/OUTPUT.gpkg
```

[image: Output (above) and Input (below)]

QGIS version 3.26.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your raster is not really converted into RGB but the GeoPackage raster driver has a peculiar behavior in how it reports the bands. See https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html#opening-options

> By default, the driver will expose a GeoPackage dataset as a four band
> (Red,Green, Blue,Alpha) dataset, which gives the maximum compatibility
> with the various encodings of tiles that can be stored. It is possible
> to specify an explicit number of bands with the BAND_COUNT opening
> option. Starting with GDAL 3.6, a special metadata item is written
> when creating a GeoPackage raster with GDAL (when using the default
> CUSTOM tiling scheme), and it is used on reading as the default number
> of bands.

However, it may be that your 1 band data is really stored as JPEG compressed RGB with the default settings. In that case use creation option TILE_FORMAT=PNG. See more info from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40425 and the linked pull requests.

You can confirm that your experience happens only with GPKG by saving the clipped raster into for example GeoTIFF.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. By changing my default settings and saving the file as a GeoTIFF  (I had gpkg as my Default output raster layer extension, now changed back to tif), the algorithm no longer reports the data in three different bands. I take it that this is because a new driver (GTiff) is used and by default will render the bands in the same way as the input raster is rendered. However, the TILE_FORMAT=PNG option doesn't work for me (I have entered it into Additional creation options as specified in the github link). I also tried TILED and PHOTOMETRIC=PALETTE, but to no avail.

Comment: In what way TILE_FORMAT=PNG did not work? Did gdal_translate give some error message?

Comment: TILE_FORMAT=PNG, when entered in Additional creation options, gives me the error "Invalid creation option: Failed GDALValidateCreationOptions() test" upon clicking Validate. When run, the error is "Warning 6: driver GTiff does not support creation option TILE_FORMAT."

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. TILE_FORMAT=PNG is a GeoPackage raster creation option https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html. The options which are supported by the GeoTIFF driver are documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification. With that creation option defined, I was able to see the result when saving to a geopackage. However, the driver still splits my output into the separate bands.

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned in the GPKG driver documentation, it is possible to avoid that a table that contains PNG tiles is reported as RGB by using open option `-oo BAND_COUNT=1`. I do not know if it is possible to use that open option with QGIS, though. You can test if it has an effect with gdalinfo.